# Taking local time and counting down the remaining hours of the day until 12:00 AM

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I've been stuck on this for awhile, I'm not even sure how to begin it because I'm a total noob with C#. At first I was utilizing `DateTime.Now` in order to get my local time, and tried to use that with `TimeSpan` in order to get how many hours are left in the day.

I've deleted that and completely started over and have hit a dead end, what do you recommend I do?

Comment: Can you show us what you did try and how _exactly_ it did not work? It's easier to help you when you show your attempt.,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
int hours = (DateTime.Today.AddDays(1) - DateTime.Now).Hours;
```

DateTime.Today.AddDays(1) gives you next date and DateTime.Now will give you system time. Now (DateTime.Today.AddDays(1) - DateTime.Now) will return total time stamp. Just call its Hours property and you will get hours left in day.

Comment: Can you expand your answer to include an explanation of your code? It helps the reader more than you might think.

Comment: DateTime.Today.AddDays(1) gives you next date and DateTime.Now will give you system time. Now (DateTime.Today.AddDays(1) - DateTime.Now) will return total time stamp. Just call its Hours property and you will get hours left in day.

Comment: Please edit your post to include that information.

Comment: Thank you very much, I dont know how I managed to hurt my head with this. I need to really look into how methods work here.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract mid night time *(DateTime)* with current time and you can access [`TimeSpan.TotalHours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours(v=vs.110).aspx) like:

```
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime midNightToday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);
var hourDifference = (midNightToday - currentTime).TotalHours;
```

Comment: I feel like an absolute idiot right now, thank you very much for your assistance. Edit: I guess hitting enter doesn't actually go down. Anyway, what I was originally doing was just... I was definitely going out of my way, thank you.

Comment: There's no need to subtract a tick here.